# Link underline appearing above text in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

On my website, I have a glitch on links in my drop-down menu. I'm using code from [Dynamic Drive jQuerySlideMenu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_multi_level_css_menu_2/).

In Firefox 19, the underlines appear above the text.

[image: How it appears in Firefox.]

This is how it's supposed to appear, in Chrome 27:

[image]

and in Internet Explorer 10:

[image]

I've inspected the elements in Firebug but I'm not sure exactly what's causing this issue. There is no CSS playing with the underline that I can see.

After some quick searching, I found [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=750917) reported in bugzilla in 2012, which is the only thing I found on underlines appearing *above* the text. It points to `vertical-align` possibly being the reason for this. I changed `vertical-align` in the slider CSS but it made no difference (`top`, `middle` or `bottom`.) I'd like to fix it. Is there anything blatantly obvious I'm missing, or some good reason this is happening?

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: may be you need to increase line height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly identified `vertical-align` as the culprit.

The hovered item is being styled by this line in jqueryslidemenu.css:

```
.jqueryslidemenu .app {
    height: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

When I remove `vertical-align` in Firebug, the problem disappears. Thus, remove `vertical-align` from that line.

If you cannot edit jqueryslidemenu.css for whatever reason, just add the following to your own css file:

```
.jqueryslidemenu .app {
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't check that the default value of `vertical-align` was `baseline`, which is why I didn't try removing the property. Thanks, and a good answer for SO, too.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `vertical-align: middle;` from `.jqueryslidemenu .app` line 54 in `jqueryslidemenu.css` and it will solve the issue.

Hence forth use [`firebug`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) which will be handy in such situations

Comment: Thanks, I do use firebug, I just needed another pair of eyes to see the solution.