# Underline text-decoration is crossing through the imported font used in Firefox

Tags: css, font-face, underline

I'm using the font [Cardiff](http://www.fontsc.com/font/cardiff) in a project and trying to apply the style `text-decoration:underline` to it.

This works fine in Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.114) but Firefox (Version. 29.0.1) the underline is crossing through the text instead of appearing under it. I believe it's something to do with the Cardiff font because when I try a 'Web Safe' font the underline is displayed correctly.

This is how the **Cardiff** font is being displayed

[image: cardiff font]

If I then change the font to **Helvetica**, this is how it's displayed

[image: helvetica font]

I've tried a few things already:

- Wrapping the font in a `span` tag, then styling this as a block and giving it a height
- I've also tried a solution provided in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771662/underlined-text-gets-crossed-in-firefox)

### Updated...

Using fixes provided by [@touko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3691688/touko) I've put together a solution that isn't really what I wanted to settle for but it works.

I've used a border for Firefox and regular `text-decoration` for other browsers.

```
h2 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Firefox specific CSS styling as explained on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css)...

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h2 {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4c2f04;
        padding-bottom: 6px;
    }
}
```

I hope someone finds a better solution than this though because it's more of a bodge job if anything.

Comment: have you tried playing with the line-height?  It might force the line lower

Comment: @Pete tried this but it didn't work, thanks for looking though.

Comment: The links on http://magicofcss.com solve this using text-shadow and a linear-gradient background-image.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an issue with the font, you could try running it through the [Font Squirrel Web Font Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I originally used this to convert the TTF file to the other formats. I could possibly try re-downloading all the original files though.

Comment: I think it also allows you to customise how the webfont is formatted, I'm not sure if that might give you some options to fix this?

Comment: I don't think it's the font though, as both Chrome and Safari are displaying it correctly.

Comment: Some browsers use different font files though, so some may be formatted differently. If it were due to your CSS it would theoretically have a similar effect on all fonts

Comment: I believe Firefox, like Chrome uses TTF by default, although I'm not sure. If this is true though, Chrome should be having the same issue.

Comment: There's a browser support table on here (not sure how up to date it is) http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/. The support does vary so, depending on the ordering of your font files in your @font-face rule, Chrome and Firefox could be using different files.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I've altered the ordering so that TTF comes first, this still hasn't fixed it.

Comment: I uploaded the font *.otf file to Font Squirrel and downloaded it again using "basic". It fixed the underline issue in firefox... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just dont use `vertical-align: middle`
The similar problem is here: [Link underline appearing above text in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836826/link-underline-appearing-above-text-in-firefox)
But looks like your problem is with a font itself.
I do not recommend to do a hack like border under the text. Search for other font.

```css
body {
  font-family: Cardiff;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/5762715ddcc2993805a83fcd2f569ea8?family=Cardiff" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#">Demo text</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourtxt-wrap{text-decoration:overline}
yourtxt-wrap{text-decoration:line-through}
yourtxt-wrap{text-decoration:underline}
```

Comment: I've tried all 3, underline and line-through appear to have the same results, where as overline does actually appear above the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use border-bottom as underline and set the space below to desirable with padding.

Comment: I thought about this, however in this case it just wouldn't work because 90% of the time the text will drop on to 2 lines or more.

Comment: just add display:inline; to styling and it fixes the problem!

Comment: This has fixed the issue on Firefox but the border is lower down on Chrome and Safari than Firefox. I could use conditional formatting to correct this but I was hoping for more of a global fix.

Comment: I'm afraid you won't find a better solution to your problem if you're intending to use cardiff font.

Comment: Have you tried using this font before? I'll more than likely use this solution at the moment.

Comment: Haven't tried using this font, had a similar problem though when I wanted the underline to be slightly lower than normally.

Comment: The links on http://magicofcss.com site solve this using text-shadow and a linear-gradient background-image.